# Marketing Cloud SDK 8.0.4 crashes

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I’m using `com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.0.4` and I have noticed that two crashes are increased since February 15th, these crashes are not new but they have increased a lot since this date.

The two crashes are:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

In the following screenshots you can see that these crashes are at the top of our crashes and how they have increased.

[image: Top Crashes]

[image: RejectedExecutionException]

[image: IllegalStateException]

and, these are the stack traces:

- RejectedExecutionException

  `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException:`
  `at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute (Executors.java:630) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration.e.a (e.java:35) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration.d.a (Unknown Source:38) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.http.c$b.a (Unknown Source:6) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.internal.g.run (Unknown Source:17) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)`
- IllegalStateException

  `java.lang.IllegalStateException:` 
  `at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:1386) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:1037) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:608) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection (SQLiteSession.java:916) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow (SQLiteSession.java:836) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow (SQLiteQuery.java:62) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow (SQLiteCursor.java:157) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount (SQLiteCursor.java:144) at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition (AbstractCursor.java:238) at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst (AbstractCursor.java:277) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.storage.db.f.d (Unknown Source:15) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.iam.m.a (Unknown Source:62) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.iam.InAppMessageComponent.onSyncReceived (Unknown Source:8) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.k$b.a (Unknown Source:18) at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.internal.g.run (Unknown Source:17) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)`

Do you know what is going on?
Do you know how to fix it?
Are you working on this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A fix is forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see version 8.0.5 of the Push SDK.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'll use the new version and check what happens with this crash. thanks for the help.